# Add info under specific line

Tags: text-processing, replace

I want to know how could I add files contain information under specific line in file.

For example, I have `file1.txt` with the following lines:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

and  `file2.txt` has the information I want to add in `file1.txt` under specific in `line 2`.

How could this to be done?

Answer (score 3):

#### Use Sed's R[ead] Command

You can use sed's [r command](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) to read in a file. For example, to match the line by its number:

```
sed '2 r /tmp/file2.txt' /tmp/file1.txt
```

Or if you prefer to match the line by its content:

```
sed '/^line 2/ r /tmp/file2.txt' /tmp/file1.txt
```

This is a standard command, and doesn't rely on any GNU extensions, so it should work across different sed implementations.

The commands above print the result on their standard output. If you want to modify the original file, add the `-i` option just after sed (this will work on Linux and Cygwin but not on all unix systems).

Comment: it just read the file1.txt but didn't add any content from file2.txt under the line 2

Comment: and the line contains special characters like this zend_extension="/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.9/php-5.2.x/ZendOptimizer.so" when i execute the command the output => sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown command: `u'

Comment: @iLinux85 The original answer matched the line by its content. See my edit for how to match by line number.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `sed` you can also do this with `awk`:

```
awk '1; /line 2/ { while(getline < "file2.txt") print }' file1.txt
```

This will insert the contents of `file2.txt` every time `line 2` is encountered.

The `1` is the default block `{ print $0 }`.

This sends its output to standard output, if you want to overwrite `file1.txt` save the output to a temporary file and overwrite:

```
awk '1; /line 2/ { while(getline < "file2.txt") print }' file1.txt > file1.txt.tmp
mv file1.txt.tmp file1.txt
```

#### Edit

For fixed string matching `==` would be more reliable, e.g. to match the mentioned string use this conditional:

```
awk '1; $0 == "\"zend_extension=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.9/php-5.2.x/ZendOptimizer.so\"" { while(getline < "file2.txt") print }' file1.txt
```

Note this needs to match the whole line.

Comment: the output :

awk: 1; /zend_extension="/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.9/php-5.2.x/ZendOptimizer.so"/ { while(getline < "xh.ini") print }
awk:                                                                ^ syntax error

Comment: Use `==` instead, see edit.

Comment: thanks for the edit , but could u set the whole command include the edit in one line ?

Comment: Answer emended.

Comment: i execute the command as it shows and i make sure the line same as in the file but the output shows the file1.txt like cat command didn't add any content after the line i specific

Comment: Then it doesn't match the line. You would get better results if you posted the exact input and expected output to the question.